# PHP Ratchet websocket connects erratic

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I have an Ubuntu server hosted on AZURE platform. The IP to SSH is 52.XX.XX.XX and if I do ***ifconfig*** it shows

```
 eth0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0d:3a:f0:8c:0d  
      inet addr:10.0.X.XX  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::20d:3aff:fef0:8c0d/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:59989423 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:81366097 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:27423133044 (27.4 GB)  TX bytes:15776052287 (15.7 GB)
```

So I assign websocket IP to eth0 IP

```
websocket = new WebSocket("ws://10.0.X.XX:9000");
```

The company who owns the server provides internet. If I try to connect websocket with internet provided by the company then my websocket connection connects. Else if I connect with other internet services it doesn't connect. But doesn't throw any message.

I am really blank help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your project on your companies local server hence it is accessible from local internet

if you want to connect from other network:
Your server must accessible from other internet through its public ip (static IP provide by ISP)
OR
You can host your project on public server.